# How to use debugging tools once a Electron app is compiled? (with electron forge)

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-forge

I built a simple app using electron, electron-forge, and Vue.

When I run my app via "electron-forge start" it works great.

When i try and compile my app with "electron-forge make" it compiles, but the app itself does not complete the back end scripts, some promise or return is not resolving.

I've determined the problem is not on the front end (vue) but something going on with node.

I've been able to get SOME debugging by setting up manual break points in the code and sending it to "mainWindow.webContents.send" and leaving the dev console on in chromium.

However, this is really taking shots in the dark. Is there any way to display the node console from a compiled electron app? this would make debugging 1000 times easier, but I can't seem to find a solution, all references are about the chromium debug console, which is not useful here.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using windows machine select the "exe" file and drag it to command prompt, then press enter.
If you are using MAC machine right click ".app" file select "Show Package Contents". Open MacOs folder inside the Contents folder, then drag the executable file and put it on terminal.
Basically put the executable on terminal and run the application you can see nodeJs console messages in it.